# Display line number per function in VIM

Tags: vim, vi

Consider for example I have a simple program with two functions. So if I do set nu command it would give a output as

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2
3 int main ()
4 {
5      printf ("main");
6      return 0;
7 }
8 int func_a()
9 {
10     printf("func_a");
11     return 0;
12 }
13 int func_b()
14 {
15     printf("func_b");
16     return 0;
17 }
```

Is there any command in VI so that I get the following display i.e., displays the total number of lines + the number of lines per function.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2
  3  int main ()
  4 1 {
  5 2     printf("main");
  6 3     return 0;
  7 4 }
  8  int func_a()
  9 1 {
 10 2     printf("func_a");
 11 3     return 0;
 12 4 }
 13  int func_b()
 14 1 {
 15 2     printf("func_b");
 16 3     return 0;
 17 4 }
```

Comment: first of all, using vim is easy to edit  your question, to make the code blocks look nicer... :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native way to do that.

You can try `:set rnu` (or in the long form `:set relativenumber`) if it suits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. Also, if it was possible, I doubt it would count the braces.

What would be the point of such a feature?

Comment: We are developing an In-house tool with such a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. But you could mis-use the *sign column* to get something like this. Dr. Chip's [RltvNmbr plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#RLTVNMBR) re-implements the `'relativenumber'` feature with signs. You may be able to leverage some of his implementation, but it would still be a major implementation effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into folding.

```
:help folds
```

Your example would look like this using folding:

[image: Example of vim folds]